# laravel - Cannot declare class Carbon\Carbon, because the name is already in use

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, php-carbon

i used the class carbon for the time in my code but i get this error

**Cannot declare class Carbon\Carbon, because the name is already in use**

this is my code

**AttendanceController.php**

```
use DateTime;
use App\User;
use App\Latetime;
use App\Attendance;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Http\Requests\AttendanceEmp;
use App\Carbon\Carbon;

class AttendanceController extends Controller
{
 public function assign(AttendanceEmp $request)
{
    $request->validated();

    if ($employee = User::whereEmail(request('email'))->first()){
        
        $mytime = Carbon::now()->format('H:i:m');
        if (Hash::check($request->pin_code, $employee->pin_code)) {
                if (!Attendance::whereAttendance_date(date("Y-m-d"))->whereUser_id($employee->id)->first()){
                    $attendance = new Attendance;
                    $attendance->user_id = $employee->id;
                    $attendance->attendance_time = $mytime;
                    $attendance->attendance_date = date("Y-m-d");

                    if (!($employee->schedules->first()->time_in >= $attendance->attendance_time)){
                        $attendance->status = 0;
                    AttendanceController::lateTime($employee);
                    };
                    $attendance->save();

                }else{
                    return redirect()->route('attendance.login')->with('error', 'you assigned your attendance before');
                }
            } else {
            return redirect()->route('attendance.login')->with('error', 'Failed to assign the attendance');
        }
    }
```

**Carbon.php**

```
namespace Carbon;

//use Carbon\Traits\Date;
use DateTime;
use DateTimeInterface;
use DateTimeZone;
class Carbon extends DateTime implements CarbonInterface
```

{
use Date;

```
/**
 * Returns true if the current class/instance is mutable.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public static function isMutable()
{
    return true;
}
}
```

this is the screenshot for the error
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2QoH.png)

Comment: have you created custom class carbon in use App\Carbon\Carbon;?  if not then namespace should be  use Carbon\Carbon;

Comment: First of all why are you creating a `Carbon` class implementing `CarbonInterface`? There is very likely a better way to achieve what you want: using macro/mixins are a different class with different name and not implementing `CarbonInterface`

Comment: The error message says that you already have declared a class with name `Carbon` somewhere before. You showed us line 500, what happens before? Is there somewhere `class Carbon`? Do you maybe use `use some\other\namespace\Carbon`? That wouldnt work too.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you copy-pasted `Carbon.php` from `nesbot/carbon` into `app/Carbon/Carbon.php` and load this file.

There is no relevant reason to do that.

Then files inside your `app/` folder in Laravel should all have a namespace starting with `namespace App\`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel, there is no reason to create Carbon class manualy, it comes out of the box. All you need is declare it in your Model:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

After that you can use all necessary functions, as example:

```
Carbon::now()->subDays(30)
```